# How many solutions does $p\mid b^q-1$ have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $\def\ge{\geqslant} \def\le{\leqslant} b\in\Bbb N^{\ge2}$ be a Natural number and $p$ be a prime such that $p\nmid b-1$. For how many primes $q$ does $$p\mid b^q-1$$
hold?

I.e. for such $b$ and $p$ let $Q(b,p)=\{q\in\Bbb P \;/\; p\mid b^q-1\}$.

Is $\#Q(b,p)$

1. Always finite?
2. Always infinite?
3. Always non-empty?
4. It depends on $b$ and $p$?

---

What I have:

Let $q,r\in \Bbb P$ and $r > q$, then
\begin{align}
p\mid b^q-1\text{ and }p\mid b^r-1
&\quad\Rightarrow\quad p\mid b^q-b^r = b^r(b^{q-r}-1)\\
&\quad\Rightarrow\quad p\mid b^{q-r}-1
\end{align}

Then due to the Euclidean algorithm it follows that $p\mid b-1$ which was excluded.  Does this mean that there is always $\#Q(b,p) \le 1$ or do I have a thinko? My intuition says that even $\#Q(b,p) = 1$, i.e. for every prime $p$ we find a sequence of ones (interpreted as number in base $b$) that is divisible by $p$. But I have no idea how to show that. Something with finite fields or so...

Answer (score 1):

Fermat tells us that $p\mid b^{p-1}-1$. Therefore, if $p\mid b^q-1$, then as you have noted, $p\mid b^d-1$, where $d=\gcd(q,p-1)$. Since $q$ is prime, $d=1$ or $d=q$. Since $p\nmid b-1$, we cannot have $d=1$. Therefore, $d=q$, that is, $q$ divides $p-1$. Thus, $Q(b,p)$ is always finite.

In fact, $\#Q(b,p) \le 1$ because $Q(b,p)$ is empty when the order of $b$ mod $p$ is not a prime and a singleton when $b$ mod $p$ is a prime, which must divide $p-1$.

Comment: So my conclusion that $\#Q\leqslant1$ is wrong, because $\varphi(p)=p-1$ might have more than one prime divisor. $b$ can have order $\varphi(p)$ because $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z^\times$ is cyclic.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts, your conclusion is right

Comment: But you say that $Q$ contains all prime divisors of $p-1$, thus there are $b$, $p$ such that $Q>1$.  Thus my conclusion must be wrong?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts,I did not say that $Q$ contains all prime divisors of $p-1$.